# Structure Automata CAML

Tags: ocaml, caml, automata

I have a problem with the CAML light language... I need to write a CAML light prog that given three 3-letter words search if the letters are present in the given words and in that case it will return true otherwise false. The program must use the deterministic automata.

Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Program without automata:

```
let string_check c1 c2 string = (index_char string c1)>0 && (index_char string c2)>0;;

let rec progCaml a b s_list = match s_list with [] -> false | x::xs -> try (string_check a b x) with Not_found -> progCaml a b xs;;
```

Comment: If I were you I think a DFA which accepts inputs which contains one specific char first. Then combine 3 such DFAs with the cubic number of states of the first one.